# How can I check the file I created already in the disk using savefileDialog in c# form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Yes Im aware this question already exist but none of them seems to answer what exactly im looking for, most of the suggest to try if (!Directory.Exists(path)), but this statement only checks if the directory exist or not and does nothing if it does exist. **But my goal is after I get the name of the folder using savefileDialog, if the folder name already exist I want to show a dialogue box to show folder already exist, would you like to rewrite the file stuff like that**

private void saveToXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        try
        {

            //Here we create a directory and including all the xml files in that directory 
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Combining my path so its pointing at the correct directory
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,  saveFileDialog1.FileName);



                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    //Initialzing where we want to create directory
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

                    //Now we are seriazling all the List instances to an XML file and storing all the XML file in the user created directory 
                    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(path + "\\TARA_Assumptions.XML", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Introduction>));
                        serializer.Serialize(stream, AssumptionInstances);
                        stream.Close();
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("Saved Assumptions OBJ to XML");
```

Comment: If you want to check if the path exist, [FolderBrowserDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.8) is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below:

```
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Directory already exists: '" + path + "'!");
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work I have tried it because when my savefileDialogue pops up the user inserts the folder name. If there is no folder with such name the folder will be created with no problem but lets say the user inserts "Test1" and there is already a folder name "Test1" it will basically take me inside that folder

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand the context of that (and still don't understand clearly). Would you like to provide some code? It will be easier to discuss with possibility of pointing something in code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my question and included code

Answer (score 0):

This should check to see if a file exists, not directory (be sure to include the extension):

```
if(System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
   SomeFunction();
}
```

'SomeFunction' should be indicating that a file exists, would you like to overwrite, etc.